# Complex join on multiple fields

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am trying to rebuild a SQL query with Linq, but run into a combined join statement. For simplicity lets limit this two two entitities A and B. The SQL part is as follows:

```
FROM Entity A
INNER JOIN Entity B WITH(NOLOCK) ON ISNULL(B.property1, B.property2) = A.property1 AND B.property3 = a.property2
```

How can I implement this using Linq?

I currently have the following:

```
from quotation in _context.Quotation
join proj in _context.Planning on new { quotation.PlanningKey, quotation.BudgetKey } equals new { proj.PlanningKey, proj.BudgetKey }
join act in _context.Planning on new { proj.ProjectKey, proj.BudgetKey } equals new { act.ProjectKey, act.BudgetKey}
where ...
orderby ...
select new
{
  ...
};
```

However this is not taking into account the "Or" part. I want to compare property 1 or 2 from entity B to property 1 from entity A AND property 3 from entity B to property 2 from entity A.

Answer (score 0):

The linq `Join` method only supports equality predicates, and AND'ing together multiple equality predicates by using anonymous objects. If you need anything else than that, you need to express it using `Where` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following snippet

```
 enityA.Join(
             enityB,
             entA => new { Property1 = entA.property1Post_id, Property2 = entA.property2Post_id }  ,
             entB => new  { Property1 = entB.property1Post_id?? entB.property2Meta, Property2 = entB.property3Meta } ,
             (entA, entB) => new { EntityA = entA, EntityB = entB }
            );
```